# Why does my computer keep forgetting node and npm installation?

Tags: node.js, installation

My computer keeps forgetting that I have node installed despite the fact that all of the files are still there. So far, I have tried installing through the node installer on the nodejs website, using brew, using nvm, and also several of the suggestions in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/isaacs/579814). No matter what I try, within a couple of hours or a couple of days, I am working away and then I am suddenly throwing node errors, and when I check `node -v` or `npm -v`, I get the error `command not found: node` or `command not found: npm`. The only thing that I can figure out to get node working again is to uninstall whatever I most recently tried and then to reinstall.

It seems like I might be having some sort of env or path issue, but I don't know where to begin to start troubleshooting anything like that.

**EDIT**

Based on the suggestion below, I added these to my `.bash_profile` and it seems to have fixed my issue. Not sure why the install wasn't adding them here or in `.bashrc`, but adding it manually fixed the issue:

```
export PATH="$HOME/.npm-packages/bin:$PATH"

export PATH="$HOME/.node_modules/bin:$PATH"
```

Comment: Is this a work or personal computer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe you forgot to add node & npm binaries to your path that's why when you open a new instance of your terminal it says that it doesn't know node and npm

Simply add the line that register the binaries into your path within your .profile file that might be located in your home directory

Comment: if it helped don't forget to mark this answer as solution

Comment: this was it! I gave it a day to freak out on me, but it hasn't! thank you so much for your suggestion!